# Fool network interface into thinking it is connected

Tags: networking, xen

I have a second NIC in my machine that I am using to create a subnet for a cluster of Xen VMs on my machine. Nothing really needs to be connected to this interface as no traffic ever needs to leave the subnet (all the Xen VMs are on the same physical machine). However, if I don't have a cable connected, the interface thinks it can't do anything and won't try to route any packets. The setup works fine when a cable is connected. Any suggestions always appreciated!

Comment: I may have found an alternate solution to this problem that I'll try out at the office tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to add a second IP to one of my NICs and this seems to be working. My problem now is that it doesn't work unless I bring up the interface again after the machine has been booted.

That is, I am now using the interfaces `eth1:0` and `eth1:1` with `xend-config.sxp` using the line
`(network-script 'network-bridge netdev=eth1'`)

Unless I do `ifup eth1:0` after the machine is started, I can't access the external network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by creating an alias of my NIC so I had two different IPs. I still need to configure the necessary `iptables` rules, but it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Will a loopback plug work for you?

[SuperLooper Loopback Plug](http://www.smartronixstore.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=product.display&Product_ID=1&CFID=345126&CFTOKEN=98463815)

Comment: Hmm, this might actually work. Not the kind of solution I was expecting, but a cool idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You need use own virtual bridge interfaсe, xenbr1 for example. Read about:
[Xen Networking](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.